# Why is $\lim_{x\to e^+} (\ln x)^{1/(x-e)} =e^{1/e}$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to e^+} (\ln x)^{1/(x-e)} =e^{1/e}$$
I started by taking ln on both side, which brings the power down, by I tried using L'Hopital, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Use $a^b = \exp(b \ln a)$ to simplify the LHS. Also note that $\searrow x_0$ and $\to x_0^+$ are two notations for the same thing but $\searrow x_0^+$ isn't really standard. I changed to the notation you seem more used to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$L=\lim_{x\searrow e} (\ln x)^{1/(x-e)} = \lim_{h\searrow 0} (\ln(e+h))^{1/h} = \lim_{h\searrow 0} \exp\left(\frac1h \ln \ln (e+h)\right)$$
Taking logarithm and using l'Hospital gives us
$$\ln L = \lim_{h\searrow 0} \frac{\ln \ln (e+h)}h = \lim_{h\searrow 0} \frac1{\ln(e+h)\cdot(e+h)} = \frac1e$$
Thus
$$L = e^{\frac1e}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to use L'Hospital, then just rewrite it as 
$$
e^{\frac{\log \log x}{x-e}}
$$
and use it, because the numerator and denominator tend to 0

Answer (score 0):

$$\displaystyle\left[\lim_{x\to e}(1+\ln x-1)^{\ln x-1}\right]^{\lim_{x\to e}\frac{x-e}{\ln x-1}}$$

Set $\ln x-1=h$ for the inner limit

For the exponent,
$$\lim_{x\to e}\frac{\ln x-1}{x-e}=\dfrac{d(\ln x)}{dx}_{(\text{at }x=e)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Write it as

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\to e}~^{x-e}\sqrt{\ln(x)}
\end{equation*}

and apply an exponential of a logarithm to this:

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\to e}\exp(\frac{\ln(\ln(x))}{x-e})=\exp(\lim_{x\to e}\frac{\ln(\ln(x))}{x-e})
\end{equation*}

since the exponential is continuous. Applying L'Hopital's rule gives

\begin{equation*}
\exp(\lim_{x\to e}\frac{1}{x\ln(x)})=\exp(\frac{1}{\lim_{x\to e}x\lim_{x\to e}\ln(x)}) =\exp(\frac{1}{1\lim_{x\to e}x})=\exp(\frac{1}{e}),
\end{equation*}

ie, $e^{(1/e)}.$